# Apply an own function to list in R

Tags: r, function, lapply

I'm starting with R.
I've taken a 2d sample in a list. This list contains 2 vectors with 100 elements either one:

```
muestra2d <- take_samples(2, 100, c(-100, 100));
```

I've a function that calculates coefficients m and b of a line in the form `y=mx+b` in a box in a given range.

```
vars <- sim_line(c(-100, 100))
```

Ok, my aim is apply a function `f(x,y)=y-ax-b` where `x` is an element of `muestra2d[1]`, `y` is an element of `muestra2d[2]`, `a` is the slope of the line (m) and  `b` is the offset of the line. The function must label the sample with the sign of the function for each pair of values (x,y).

I've tried it with this line

```
result <- lapply(muestra2d, function(x,y) (y-(vars[5]*x)-vars[6]))
```

thinking lapply takes an element from the first vector of the list and copies it in `x`, doing the same for `y` and applying the function to this values, but it isn't a good idea.

How I can do this? How I can plot the line, points and negative points with another color at the same time?

Comment: Arithmetics in R is vectorised, so you can just write something like `result <- muestra2d[1, ] - vars[5] * muestra2d[2, ] - vars[6]`. I might not have the  indexing right because I don't know how the output of `take_samples()` looks.

Comment: Output of `take_samples()` returns a list of two vectors. You're seeing muestra2d like a matrix. I've reinterpreted your expression like this: `result <- muestra2d[[1]] - vars[5] * muestra2d[[2]] - vars[6]`. With this, I'm evaluating the expression for the same index in first vector and second of muestra2d. Thanks for your comment, my friend.

Comment: `2dsample` is not a valid name for an object.

Comment: Thx for your comment, jogo, I'm spanish, so, I've called it `muestra2d` it seems it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1L);
take_samples <- function(sample.num,elem.num,box) lapply(seq_len(sample.num),function(i) runif(elem.num,box[1L],box[2L]));
sim_line <- function(box) c(1,0);
box <- c(-100,100);
muestra2d <- take_samples(2L,100L,box);
vars <- sim_line(box);
signs <- sign(muestra2d[[2L]] - vars[1L]*muestra2d[[1L]] - vars[2L]);
par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i');
plot(NA,xlim=box,ylim=box,xlab='x',ylab='y',main='plot');
abline(vars[2L],vars[1L]);
with(setNames(muestra2d,c('x','y')),{
    points(x[signs>=0],y[signs>=0],col='green');
    points(x[signs<0],y[signs<0],col='red');
});
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Awesome, my friend. It's what I'm looking for but I'm beginner and it's difficult to me understanding your code.

Comment: After read and re-read your code, at the end works in my purpose. I had to reinterpret and rewrite some things but you gave me real help. Thanks for all!